# Is there a csv files naming convention?

Tags: php

I must download data from external csv file which is originally named 403-002-20220107.csv.

```
$csvfile = "C:\wamp64\importcsv\403-002-20220701_F.csv "; //Nom du fichierCSV
if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
     die("Fichier introuvable. Assurez-vous que vous avez précisé le bon chemin pour ce Fichier." );
}
```

I got this warning message:

> ( ! ) Warning: Octal escape sequence overflow \403 is greater than
> \377

as well as a "File not found" message.

After renaming the file as follows (name starting with a letter):

```
$csvfile = "C:\wamp64\importcsv\A403-002-20220701_F.csv "; //Nom du fichierCSV
```

it worked fine. Is this behaviour conforming with a specific file naming convention in PHP?

Comment: Use single quotes or escape backslash.

Comment: as @u_mulder the problem is in your string literal. When using double quotes, there are some escape sequences allowed and in your case the symbol `\403` gets escaped to a character in octal notation .. here for more details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Both solutions worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use backslashes for file names - I know this is the Windows convention, but in programming languages a backslash in a string means "[escape sequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) is starting" which is used to put non-printable characters in a string.

You should always use forward slashes for path delimiting, even in Windows - it works fine and will not introduced unwanted behaviour.